# Unable to connect to Marklogic database port 8000 using Java

Tags: java, marklogic

I am unable to connect to Marklogic port 8000 using Java code base and getting following error: I am using admin to connect to this Documents database

2017-09-07 12:14:58.494  INFO 25192 --- [           main] c.h.c.b.testdata.DatabaseIndexWorker     :  ...using indexes in file [range-path-index.json]

2017-09-07 12:14:58.496  INFO 25192 --- [           main] c.h.c.b.testdata.DatabaseIndexWorker     :  ...reading admin credentials

2017-09-07 12:14:58.496  INFO 25192 --- [           main] c.h.c.b.testdata.DatabaseIndexWorker     :  ...URL is http://localhost:8002/manage/LATEST/databases/Documents/properties

2017-09-07 12:14:59.141  INFO 25192 --- [           main] .h.c.b.p.BackendPersistenceConfiguration : Connecting to MarkLogic database at localhost:8000

2017-09-07 12:14:59.142  WARN 25192 --- [           main] .h.c.b.p.BackendPersistenceConfiguration : Connecting to MarkLogic database without SSL

2017-09-07 12:14:59.175 DEBUG 25192 --- [           main] c.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices   : Connecting to localhost at 8000 as admin

2017-09-07 12:14:59.405 DEBUG 25192 --- [           main] c.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices   : Requesting head for some_document_that_does_not_need_to_exist in transaction null

2017-09-07 12:14:59.507  INFO 25192 --- [           main] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8000: Connection reset

2017-09-07 12:14:59.509  INFO 25192 --- [           main] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8000

2017-09-07 12:14:59.512  INFO 25192 --- [           main] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8000: Connection reset

2017-09-07 12:14:59.512  INFO 25192 --- [           main] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8000

2017-09-07 12:14:59.519  INFO 25192 --- [           main] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8000: Connection reset

2017-09-07 12:14:59.519  INFO 25192 --- [           main] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8000

2017-09-07 12:14:59.522  WARN 25192 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'testDataApplication': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'databaseClient' defined in com.hbi.ce.backend.persistence.BackendPersistenceConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClient]: Factory method 'databaseClient' threw exception; 
nested exception is com.hbi.ce.backend.common.ConnectionException: There is something wrong with the MarkLogic connection; nested exception is com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

2017-09-07 12:14:59.528  INFO 25192 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

While if I try to open page 
https://localhost:8000/qconsole/ : it works fine
But this one doesn't works : http://localhost:8000/qconsole/

Admin user has rest reader, rest writer and rest admin privileges.

If I try to create a separate database (test and attached forest test-01 and created corresponding rest server on port 8015, I am able to connect using this port). But with this I am unable to create writeBatcher using dataMovementManager api of Marklogic.

Any inputs what is going wrong ?

I am facing same issue on Marklogic 8 as well as 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll only be able to use writeBatcher and dataMovementManager on Marklogic 9 as they require undocumented REST endpoints that are not in MarkLogic 8.

If you can only connect to https on port 8000 then you must have an "ssl certificate template" installed on that app server (App-Sevices 8000).  See the admin page for that app server to remove that ssl certificate template.

For more information, see [Configuring SSL on App Servers](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/SSL) in the Security Guide.